# Eclipse Code Autocompletion for CodeIgniter AFTER using CI_Loader Class

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter, autocomplete

For a couple of days I'm trying to get Autocompletion in Eclipse PDT for the CodeIgniter PHP Framework.

At the moment I'm in a state where I **can get** Code Completion for all the CI Classes ( CI_Session, CI_Loader, etc.). For example when using:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(...); // Code Completion Works!!!
```

(I used an extra php file to get this working)

```
/**
* ...
* @property CI_Xmlrpc $xmlrpc CI_Xmlrpc
* @property CI_Xmlrpcs $xmlrpcs CI_Xmlrpcs
* @property CI_Zip $zip CI_Zip
*/

class CI_Controller {};
```

---

What **isn't** working is getting autocompletion when using the CI_Loader Class to load a specific helper .php file (array_helper.php, url_helper.php, etc.). For example when using:

```
$this->load->helper('url'); // load the helper
$mop= url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE); // No Code Completion!!!
```

Does anyone has a solution to this problem?

Comment: here is a solution for netbeans, see if you can port it to eclipse.  
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/184716/

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. the script is just generating a file that does not include the helper functions und therefore does exactly the same as my current solution...